# Additional payment on top of defined Plan in Stripe using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, stripe-payments

On Stripe is there any API where customer can pay additional charges along with the Plan amount within single transaction ?
Scenario is, total amount of charge is based on number of users. Means say 1 user has $100 need to charged and base plan amount is of $3000. While purchasing the license customer has to define number of users, say 5 (So 5*100=500) + 3000 (base plan amount) So total should be $3500 should pay within single transaction. number of users may varies. So how to code for Stripe for this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you would create your $100 plan and set the `quantity` depending on the number of users your customer currently has so that with a quantity of 5 he ends up paying $500. You can update the quantity and let Stripe handle the proration.

You would then use [Invoice Items](https://stripe.com/docs/api#invoiceitems) to change the amount you want to charge your customer on each billing cycle. Invoice items get added automatically to the customer's next invoice so that you could charge $3000 + $500 for example.

You would then have to use Stripe's [webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks) to be notified about events that happen in your Stripe account. ﻿That way you can listen for the `invoice.created` event and create an invoice item for this invoice to change the amount billed to this customer.

In the end, here are the steps you'd follow:

- Create a customer in Stripe with the card token.
- Create the first $3000 Invoice Item for the first invoice since that one is always closed by default.
- Create the subscription to the $100 monthly plan with the expected `quantity`. This will automatically bill the Invoice Item created before.
- Each month, listen for the `invoice.created` event and create a new Invoice Item for $3000.

Another solution which some people find easier to build would be to use the `quantity` parameter of the subscription to charge a different amount to each customer. You would create a $1 monthly plan for example and set the quantity to 3100 for customers who pay only for one user ($3100) or 3500 for the ones with 5 users ($3500). This is also detailed in the [subscriptions guide](https://stripe.com/docs/guides/subscriptions#setting-quantities).